# How can i create a hyphen sign with css only along with P tag

Tags: html, css

I want to create a hyphen sign with the p tag . It is requirement. I am successful to create it with the border but issue is in alignment . here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxu4oyea/3/) . **I want the hyphen sign into middle** . Please help me .
I have used these properties

```
border-left: 2px solid;
height: 3px;
border-width: 11px;
```

```css
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
.middle-arrow
{
    border-left: 2px solid;
    height: 3px;
    border-width: 11px;
}
```

```html
<p>25 july,2014</p>
<p class="middle-arrow">25 july,2015</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wxu4oyea/7/)**

Instead of trying with `border`, you can use `:before`

```
p.middle-arrow:before
{
    content:"-";
    font-size:20px;
    padding:0 5px; /* use padding if you need space in between 2 <p> tags
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also did this before the @G.L.P's answer with this . Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wxu4oyea/8/) . But I'll accept his answer.

```
.middle-arrow:before {
    border-left: 2px solid;
    height: 3px;
    border-width: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
}
```